# Saving to xlsx file in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to read around 50K files in a folder, extract some details from each file and write to an excel file. I am using the below code:-

```
string savLoc = textBox2.Text.Trim();
savLoc = savLoc + "\\Visible_Fields.xlsx";
xlWorkBook.SaveAs(savLoc, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
xlApp.DisplayAlerts = true;
xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
xlApp.Quit();
```

But the xlsx file created is not openeing and showing its corrupted. But if I use extension as xls, it will work but xls is having a limitation of 65K in one worksheet. Can anyone tell me how this can be done? I can use only excel interop not any other free libraries.

I use the interop version 14

Comment: You're going to want to look at which version of the Office interop libraries you are using. If you are using the pre-2007 versions, then this obviously won't work.

Comment: Hello.. I am using Interop version 14, I have office 2010 installed in my machine.

Comment: Try `Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook` instead of `Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal`. This will produce a non-macro enabled `.xlsx` file.

Answer (score 3):

The best solution to this problem would be to not use Interop. It's based on the COM+ pipeline and just isn't that reliable. Instead, I would recommend you use third-party libraries that will be able to open your file, parse it and make the content available to you in a .NET native way, which is much more safe.

- [Closed XML](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/)
- [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/)
- [NPOI](https://npoi.codeplex.com/)
- [Excellibrary](https://code.google.com/p/excellibrary/)

There is a ton of projects to avoid using Interop. The one is usually prefer is EPPlus.

Comment: +1 the best solution, if not having Excel good enough to solve the problem. I don't know those others, but I've used Closed XML, but thanks for the list and I'll look at EPPlus.

Comment: It is worth noting that most of these are actually wrappers for the [Microsoft OpenXML SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854(v=office.15).aspx), which is actually First Party. Thus I would actually say that in effect these are 1st party solutions, since the file generation is fully supported by Microsoft.

Comment: I agree with you in general, but not fully since Excellibrary and NPOI work with the pre-2007 .xls format. Those are not compliant to the OpenXML standard and therefore cannot be based upon OpenXML SDK. Also, I found that working with EPPlus was way more efficient than the OpenXML SDK from Microsoft. The learning curve is way smoother.