# c# xls or csv clear formats programatically

Tags: c#, csv, format

I have a csv file.

In our application we need to clear formats csv programmatically.

Without clear formats we are unable to import the file in application.

We cannot use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel because microsoft office is not installed on the system.

We are using infragistics.

Is there any way to clear formats programmatically without using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.

Is there any other way by which without installing microsoft office on the system we can clear formats of file or by using infragistics interop.

To be clear we clear formats of a file in microsoft excel is cleared using edit->clear->formats.

Comment: you can use third party excel libraries such as npoi. (https://npoi.codeplex.com/ )

Comment: This question has many duplicates and is addressed here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23856867/saving-to-xlsx-file-in-c-sharp/23857064#23857064

Comment: Hi @mcy, i downloaded the NPOI library and tried to found the way to clear the formats of complete file, i did not find a way. Will you please explain how this library will be useful?

Comment: @gretro i did not find exact duplicate of my problem.I need it urgently, will you please help me?

Comment: The answer I proposed at that link lists different solution to avoid using Interop. EPPlus also provides a good solution for the style of the cells.

Comment: .csv files are comma-separated values, so I created an excel file, added some formatting, and saved as a .csv file. When I re-opened it with notepad and Excel itself, there were no formatting in both. How do you save formatting in a .csv file?

Comment: @mcy we cant save formatting in csv file, but after clear formatting columns having date time format changed to numbers from date time value. we need the formats clear before proceeding import in the application.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this library for a simple export tool before, it was pretty easy to use.
The tool I used it for wasnt too complex so i cant tell you how it scales up. Might be worth having a look.

http://epplus.codeplex.com/

Comment: Hi @Isbs i am using epplus but did not find a way to clear format of file. Will you please suggest.

Comment: Its been a while and I dont have an active project to test it on, but I think you had so select a range of cells and then do something like cells.style.format = 0;
I'm sorry I can't be more of a help